# File-upload saves empty file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am writing file uploading module in c# using ajax&jQuery on ASP.NET MVC 5

I tried msdn example for backend code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload()
    {
        if (Request.Files.Count != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                var file = Request.Files[i];
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Junk/"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
        }

        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

The problem is that this method creates empty file (size 0 bytes). I guess this happens because we don't read input stream, we're only reading filename on the example.

How to make this work?

**Update 1 (posted js code):**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Upload").click(function () {
            var formData = new FormData();
            var totalFiles = document.getElementById("FileUpload").files.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
                var file = document.getElementById("FileUpload").files[i];

                formData.append("FileUpload", file);
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Home/Upload',
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                //beforeSend: beforeSendHandler,
                success: function(){
                    alert("CAT");
                },
                //error: errorHandler,
                // Form data
                data: formData,
                //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            });
            ajaxRequest.done(function () {
                alert("CAAT");
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

**Update 2 (added html-markup):**

```
<div class="container body-content">
        <hr />
        <input type="file" id="FileUpload" multiple />
        <input type="button" id="Upload" value="Upload" />
        <hr />
        <footer>
       ...
        </footer>
    </div>
```

Comment: post your javascript code also

Comment: @RachitGupta , posted js.
(if isn't difficult, can anyone please also explain difference btw using "ajaxRequest.done" outside the request and "success: function(){...}," inside the request.

Comment: @R.Matveev: `ajaxRequest.done` : It means your ajax request complete with error or without error it doesn't matter.
but in Case of `"success.function(){}"` it means it will hit only when ajax request got success ..

Comment: Merci, @SunilKumar , it's clear now.

Comment: @R.Matveev: Regarding your question, Can you please post your html code !..

Comment: Ideally, we need to see your HTML for your form as @SunilKumar said. Off the top of my head, you will need to declare the form's `enctype` as `multipart/form-data` in order to POST files; like so: `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" ...>`. Until we see your HTML/`form` code, it is hard to tell.

Comment: @GeoffJames , I try to avoid binding Upload event on a form. 
To make things clear: once on a specific site I saw a way of doing this without form, but I don't know their backend code; nevertheless, their page worked well.

Comment: @R.Matveev OK. It's not very clear in your question that you're trying to avoid using a form - hence all of the answers being `form` oriented. Also, do you have a link to this particular site you're on about? Maybe someone is able to reverse-engineer it? Could you post these in your OP?

Comment: @GeoffJames , I have a link, but that site requires not very easy registration process, you would need to have a mobile number of the particular country to finish up the registration. But I can reverse-engineer it by myself and provide all necessary information. And I even done this before, there wasn't any `<form>...</form>`-like markup. There was only `<input ... />` tag.

Comment: @R.Matveev I see. That's fair enough. I've done a bit of digging, it may be worth reading this: https://cmatskas.com/upload-files-in-asp-net-mvc-with-javascript-and-c/ - it's *very* similar to what you already have, but using an `id` parameter and a couple of other differences. It also outlines that your browser needs to support `window.formData` in order for the POST to work. I hope this might help :)

Comment: @GeoffJames , Exactly what I need!! It works. Moreover, I just realised that probably my previous solution worked too. Cause, I have been testing it on a small .txt file from desktop (as I supposed), but it wasn't just small file, it was empty.

Comment: @GeoffJames , Could you please make an answer to this question (with your link; or better copy and paste that code to your answer here, with a link to that site, for historical reasons), I can't accept a comment. Also, that mate from the site has around 3-4 not critical mistakes in his code. Thank you for help.

Comment: I've added my answer, adapting the previous link I posted. I understand it may not be *exactly* what you need, but you should be able to copy/paste and adapt it to suit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there with your current code.

I've read about this one on: https://cmatskas.com/upload-files-in-asp-net-mvc-with-javascript-and-c/ and adapted my answer.

Try this:

### Your upload section:

```
// The same as you already have,  but your button as a "button"
<div ...>

    <input type="file" id="FileUpload" multiple />
    <button type="button" id="Upload" value="Upload" />
    ...
</div>
```

### Your jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Upload").click(function () {
            var files = $("FileUpload").target.files;
            if (files.Length > 0)
            {
                // Check if the browser supports FormData
                if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
                    var formData = new FormData();
                    // Add the files 
                    for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x++){
                        data.append("file" + x, files[x]);
                    }

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: 'Home/Upload?id=someId'
                        data: formData,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        //beforeSend: beforeSendHandler,
                        success: function(){
                            alert("CAT");
                        },
                        //error: errorHandler,
                        // Form data
                        data: formData,
                        //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false
                    });
                    ajaxRequest.done(function () {
                        alert("CAAT");
                    });
                }
                else {
                    // If the browser does not support FormData, show an alert
                    alert("Your browser does not support this type of upload");
                }
            }); 
        }
    });
</script>
```

### Your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(string id)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string file in Request.Files)
        {
            var fileContent = Request.Files[file];
            if (fileContent != null && fileContent.ContentLength > 0)
            { 
                // get a stream
                var stream = fileContent.InputStream;
               // and write the file to disk
               var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file); 
               var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Junk"), fileName); 
               using (var fileStream = File.Create(path))
               {
                   stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
               }
           }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return Json("Upload failed");
    }

    return Json("Upload succeeded");
}
```

Please note you might want to change a couple of things around, but this should be pretty much what you need.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
var Image = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images/Attachment"), Image);
file.SaveAs(path);
}
```

and in View section

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

<input type="file" name="file"/>
<button type="submit" Submit</button>
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: yes I know how to do this through forms, but I have very strong reasons to do this another way. Also, this is not for Images, but some filetypes I will define later.

Comment: The author trying to achieve this through jQuery Ajax, Your answer not full fill the author requirement.

Comment: Whilst I agree that saving as an image is a bit of a misconception on the @Rosan's part - I think that this answer *isn't* worthy of a downvote, as it wasn't stated in the OP that you require it in JS *only* - OP question is tagged as MVC and this is using a practice through MVC.

Comment: And just because I'm picky (but feeling nice). In order to use Ajax - as per OP - you will need to declare the form with `@using (Ajax.BeginForm(...)) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Possible way to do this:

```
 <form id="form1">
      <input accept="image/*" type="file" id="txtFileInpu" />
      <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
      </form>
```

JS

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var form = document.getElementById('form1').onsubmit = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var formdata = new FormData(); 
            var fileInput = document.getElementById('txtFileInput');
            if (fileInput != "" && fileInput.files.length > 0) {
                for (i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
                    formdata.append(fileInput.files[i].name, fileInput.files[i]);
                }
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('POST', '/Controller/Upload');
                xhr.send(formdata);
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                        var result = xhr.responseText;
                        if(result=="Uploaded")
                              //file uploaded
                         else
                             //file not uploaded
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        }

    </script>
```

C#

```
public string Upload()
    {
        try
        {
             for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i];

                string strTargetFolder = Server.MapPath("~/Junk");

                if (!Directory.Exists(strTargetFolder))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(strTargetFolder);
                }

                string targetPath = Path.Combine(strTargetFolder, file.FileName);
                file.SaveAs(targetPath);

            }
            return "Uploaded";
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            return "ERROR";
        }


}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a solution (upvoted). But I can't accept it cause I don't want use forms, and nothing changed in backend part.